# Hide "See all " link of list/document webPart in modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, document-library, modern-experience

I want to prevent users from opening the library/list source. I created views and I don't want them access to the original list/library and switch between views or modify them.

So how I can hide this link from modern page?

[image]

I can accomplish this in the classic mode by embedded CSS into the page, but now with the modern page there is no script editor web part to do that.

Answer (score 5):

We can install [react script editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) in site, and add the modern script editor web part into modern page with the code below to hide the "See all".

```
<style>
a[aria-label='See all']{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Refer to: [Add The Script Editor Webpart back to SharePoint Modern Experience](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)

Or we can inject a custom Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) on modern pages using SPFx.

[react application injectcss](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

Comment: Works a treat!!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has recently added a new option to Show/Hide "see all" link in list/library web part property pane settings.

Check below article for detailed steps to Hide "See all" link of list/document web part in modern page: [Show/Hide See All link from SharePoint list/library web parts](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/11/18/show-hide-see-all-link-from-sharepoint-list-library-web-parts/)