# SharePoint Online - Remove Switch View Option from Modern List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

Is it possible to remove the abilty to change views from a modern list?

I have a few views of a certain list and would like users to only be able to see the views to which they have a link. (I would set the default to a view which anyone could see with no issues)

I've done a fair amount of Googling but can't tell if this is possible or not (could view formatting do it?)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can apply third-party CSS styles or SPFx to hide the “Switch view options” from modern list view, but it will affect all users accessing the list.

See the references below:

[Reference third-party CSS styles in SharePoint Framework web parts.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/reference-third-party-css-styles)

[Hide “See all ” link of list/document webPart in modern page.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260239/hide-see-all-link-of-list-document-webpart-in-modern-page)

Comment: Hmm this looks like it might be the right way, unfortunately I don't think I have the admin privaliges, nor the expertise to pull it off.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: SPFX is not possible also as we can not edit default list view form